# Running a Python function from Ansible script

Tags: python, django, ansible

I have a Django project hosted on a remote server. This contains a file called `tmp_file.py`. There's a function called `fetch_data()` inside that file. Usually I follow the below approach to run that function.

```
# Inside Django Project

$ python manage.py shell

[Shell] from tmp_file import feth_data

[Shell] fetch_data()
```

Also the file doesn't contain `__name__` section. So can't run as a stand alone script. What's the best way to perform this task using Ansible. I couldn't find anything useful from Ansible docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's `--command` switch for `shell` django-admin [command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/#shell).

So you can try in Ansible:

```
- name: Fetch data
  command: "django-admin shell --command='from tmp_file import feth_data; fetch_data()'"
  args:
    chdir: /path/to/tmp_file
```